# Suggestions for exporting Oracle Clob data to csv using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, csv, export, clob

Can you please suggest how can we export the oracle clob data field to csv file. The table contain other regular data types too. And also if the clob data cannot fit in a csv what are the other options available?

Thanks, Naveen

Comment: Technically Clob field can contain upto 4GB of data. If I am suppose to load more records of count 1000's. The file size will be huge and the users cannot view the complete data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing CLOBs in a CSV file is possible if you use a serious CSV writer that supports:

- Multi-line fields
- Doubling of double quotes
- Setting the encoding

Then you can read the exported file in any other application that has a serious CSV parser, such as Excel.

Just don't go for any CSV classes that have the word *simple* in their name. They certainly will be too simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can read clob's just like strings. new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection() and so on. When you have the data, you can write CSV's with a StreamWriter because they are just text files.